# How to prevent Spring Batch Job to from being restarted on step fail?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud

I have simple single-step job:

```
@Bean(name = "restProcessorJob")
public Job job(@Qualifier("step") Step step) throws Exception {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("restProcessorJob")
            .start(step)
            .build();
}
```

And if there was exception during step execution, Batch framework will try to execute it again immediately.

```
2016-12-12 18:49:45.558  INFO 10872 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=restProcessorJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{id=1481568585432}]
2016-12-12 18:49:45.572  INFO 10872 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step]
2016-12-12 18:49:45.597 DEBUG 10872 --- [           main] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Created GET request for "http://myhost:myport.."
2016-12-12 18:49:45.646 DEBUG 10872 --- [           main] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Setting request Accept header to [application/json, application/*+json]
2016-12-12 18:49:46.670 ERROR 10872 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step step in job restProcessorJob

org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    ... 

2016-12-12 18:49:46.689  INFO 10872 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=restProcessorJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{id=1481568585432}] and the following status: [FAILED]
2016-12-12 18:49:46.690  INFO 10872 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner   : Running default command line with: []
2016-12-12 18:49:46.727  INFO 10872 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=restProcessorJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{id=1481568585432}]
2016-12-12 18:49:46.736  INFO 10872 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step]
...
```

Is there any way to configure such behavior and do not run the job twice on fail?

**EDIT:**

It seems that I've found the source of problem. Spring boot application tries to launch every CommandLineRunner it founds in the context. In my case it is the *org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner*. I have been trying to exclude this class:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(excludeName="org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner")
```

But without success...

Answer (score 1):

Use .preventRestart with an incrementer

```
@Bean(name = "restProcessorJob")
public Job job(@Qualifier("step") Step step) throws Exception {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("restProcessorJob")
            .start(step)
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .preventRestart()
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Why I shoud use incrementer with preventRestart? Setting preventRestart flag to the job without incrementer won't have any effect?

Comment: This was a long time back and I think since then the framework had a lot of changes. But this worked for me 5 years back :)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it in your config file, you can put the skip limit to 0

Comment: Doesn't _skip limit_ means the number of times exception should be ignored before step get failed? If so, it is not what i need, I want step & job to be failed, but Job should be executed only once.

Comment: you also have the retry limit, if you do have a skip limit to 0 will fail after the first exception